# I changed my nixos channel to unstable, why are my packages still not updated?

Tags: nix, nixos

How do I update my packages from the `nixos-18.09` channel to the `nixos-unstable` channel? I am trying to do this as I need to use updated versions of some packages.

Following the directions in the [nixos manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-channels), I have added the `nixos-unstable` channel `https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable`, removed the `nixos-18.09` channel `https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-18.09`,
and run `$ nix-channel --update` and `$ sudo nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade`.

Still, however, my installed packages are the old versions. I have also tried `$ nix-env -u '*'` and still have the old versions. What else do I need to do to update my packages to the `nixos-unstable` versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to do this as I need to use updated versions of some
>   packages.

You can use packages from different channels. So possibly keeping your default channel as stable, and just referencing particular packages from the unstable channel might be a better solution.

I have the following import in my config (using `google-chrome` from the channel I have assigned to `unstable`):

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:


let
  unstable = import <unstable> {
    config = config.nixpkgs.config; 
  };
in
{
   environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
     awscli
     google-cloud-sdk
     kubectl
     libreoffice
     # ...
     unstable.google-chrome
   ];
}
```

---

As to why your packages are not using the unstable channel, probably because they reference the `nixos` channel which you did not seem to modify (you seemed to only add a channel named `nixos-unstable`, but nothing referenced this channel name most probably).

Answer (score 2):

To change to the unstable NixOS channel:

1. Become root; You want to change the *root* user's Nix channel: `su`
2. Remove the NixOS channel: `nix-channel --remove nixos`
3. Add the NixOS unstable channel and ensure it's named *nixos*: `nix-channel --add nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable`

Then you can upgrade as you normally would. For example, `nixos-rebuild --upgrade boot` will first update the NixOS channel and then install packages from the updated channel. Upon reboot you'd be updated.

**Note:** I advise against doing `nixos-rebuild --upgrade switch`, especially when changing channels, simply because NixOS won't restart all services anyway. Therefore the *switch* would be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change all the packages to unstable

```
{ pkgs, ... }@args:
let
  pkgsUrl = "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz";
  pkgs = import (builtins.fetchTarball pkgsUrl) {};
in
{...}
```